# Getting rid of java.util.Iterator

Tags: java

My problem is related to Java.  I don't like the `java.util` package because of the optional methods.  For instance, I don't like it that, when I return a `List`, I have to prevent the user to modify the list; I would like to return a list that implements, say, interface `UnmodifiableList` (yes, I know about `Collections.unmodifiableList()`, but for many reasons, I don't like to encapsulate my list).  On the other hand, when I am given a list from an external piece of code, this list could be a1) unmodifiable, a2) modifiable with side-effects on the object that returned me the list, or a3) modifiable without side-effects, and b1) immutable (assuming the elements in the list are immutable as well) or b2) mutable and unsafe to use as a key.

I can rewrite most existing classes (just copy/paste the `java.util` package) and introduce interfaces `UnmodifiableList`, `ModifiableList`, etc. without much effort.  However, I have the following problem: I really like the forall mechanism

```
for (final Object o: listOfObjects) {
  // do something
}
```

which uses class `java.lang.Iterable`, which uses `java.util.Iterator`.

So my problem is, how should I cope with the `Iterator` class?

I have several possible solutions but I am looking for the most elegant.

1. Is it possible to make java use a different class than `Iterable` for the forall loops?
2. If not, is it possible to mark `java.util.Iterator.remove()` as deprecated?
3. Also, is it possible to customise my IDEs (eclipse and netbeans) so that they warn me every time I use `Iterator`?

My current plan is to define my own `Iterator`, as an extension of `java.util.Iterator`, and to mark the `remove()` method as deprecated.  Next, I will have some script looking at my code and making sure that `java.util` is used nowhere (except in the definition of my own `Iterator`).  That way, I should be safe.

Edit: Thanks for your advises and links, guys.  Cheers.

Comment: What's wrong with `Iterator` ??

Comment: The normal way to do that is to just let the optional operation `remove` throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

It comes with the downside that there is no compile-time check and the IDE shows a method that is not really meant to be called. Anyway, I would do it like this, since working against the common practice of a language or framework usually creates more pain than gain.

Comment: With Eclipse (and NetBeans I suppose) there are many plugins that will yell a warn under   some  conditions. Take a look at CheckStyle plugin. (Question 3)

Comment: You might have a look at Guava, which already has ImmutableList, UnmodifiableIterator, etc.

Comment: Related question [Why were Java collections implemented with "optional methods" in the interface](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/77897/why-were-java-collections-implemented-with-optional-methods-in-the-interface).

Comment: @tantale, perhaps you are trying to solve a theorical problem which doens't need to be solved. What is the actual situation hyou have which you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 5):

I will not go into the wisdom (or lack thereof) of replacing `java.util.*`, but as far as `Iterable` and `Iterator` go:

- You cannot *replace* `Iterable` in foreach loops - it's practically hardcoded in the Java compiler.
- The Java specification allows for throwing a perfectly fine `UnsupportedOperationException` when an optional operation is, well, unsupported. What is wrong with that? If your testsuite has proper coverage, you would know immediately, anyway. The abstract implementations of several Java interfaces (`Abstract*`) throw an exception for unsupported operations by default.
- If your code is trying to remove objects from a Collection that does not support it, you probably have greater problems than deciding what to do with `remove()`. And if you are passing collections to third-party code, something *will* break if you violate the Java interfaces.
- You could always override `remove()` with a method that does nothing to silence any errors... if you can take unexpected breakage in code that expects removed items to *be* removed.

Comment: It's hardcoded in the compiler. The JVM knows nothing of high-level constructs such as "for loops".

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in reading the official FAQ that explains some design choices made for java Collections : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/collections/designfaq.html#1

There are quite good reasons for having optional operations. If you really want compiler support to manage the mutability of your types, your best bet is to use Scala and its Collection library. The type system of Scala is more suitable for checking such constraints.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a list from a method, but do not want to let the user of the method change the list used in your code, you can always return a copy of the list:

```
return new ArrayList<?>(oldArrayList);
```

Rewriting the entire collection library is not likely to make you end up with a program that performs better and is easier to maintain compared to using the standard API.

Comment: *Rewriting the entire collection library is not likely to make you end up with a program that performs better:* Too true. As a matter of fact, due to field visibility issues, merely *moving* e.g. the HashMap implementation outside the java.util package results in slower code...